# Laravel filter date range with date range columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If the selected dates ($postFr, $postTo) are within defined periods, I want to list the related products. So can I do something like the following example?

example:

```
$q->whereBetween('start_date', array($postFr, $postTo));
$q->orWhereBetween('end_date', array($postFr, $postTo));

//Could there be a similar use like this???;

$q->whereBetween(array(start_date, end_date), $postFr);
$q->orWhereBetween(array(start_date, end_date), $postTo);
```

**Detailed explanation:**

I have a periods table like this

```
periods

|  id  |  start_date  |  end_date  | product_id |   
|------|--------------|------------|------------|
|  1   | 2021-02-19   | 2021-03-21 |  1         |   
|  2   | 2021-02-19   | 2021-03-21 |  2         |   
|  3   | 2021-02-19   | 2021-03-21 |  3         |   
|  4   | 2021-02-19   | 2021-03-21 |  2         |
```

and I have a products table like this

```
products

|   id  |   name    |
|-------|-----------|
|   1   |   pro1    |
|   2   |   pro2    |
|   3   |   pro3    |
```

The relevant codes on my model page are as follows

```
public $belongsTo = [
        'relationPeriod' => [
            'Model->periods table',
            'key' => 'id',
            'otherKey' => 'product_id',
        ]
 ]
 
 $query->whereHas('relationPeriod', function($q) use ($postFr, $postTo){
     $q->whereBetween('start_date', array($postFr, $postTo]));
     $q->orWhereBetween('end_date', array($postFr, $postTo));
 });
```

Comment: `array(start_date, end_date)` is not valid php

Comment: your first line of code `$q->whereBetween('start_date', array($postFr, $postTo]));` you are using array() & ] together ?

Comment: @Berto99 I know, I asked if there is a use like this.

Comment: @bhucho no, it was wrong. ignore.

Answer (score 1):

it works

```
$q->whereDate('start_date', '<=', $postFr);
$q->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $postFr);
$q->orWhereDate('start_date', '<=', $postTo);
$q->whereDate('end_date', '>=', $postTo);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
$start_date = '2021-01-01';
$end_date = '2021-02-01';
$filter = Atom_juice_data_history::whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date, $end_date])
            ->where('atom_juice_data_id',$product_id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

This is reference url
https://medium.com/@sectheater/how-to-use-laravel-wherebetween-method-elegantly-20a50f3b0a2a

Comment: This doesn't provide a valid answer. In OP there is a comparison between date range (start_date,end_date) with  input date range  ($postFr, $postTo). Read question again